# Web API 2 REST route

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I would like to use part of route request as a input string to next Rest Request

e.g

```
http://host-uri/api/controller/{{querystring}} 

http://host-uri/api/controller/abc/xyz/123
```

In the above 
querystring = abc/xyz/123

on controller

```
HttpResponseMessage GetMessage(string querystring)
{
   //some operation using querystring 

   return response; 
}
```

Is this possible ?

Note : I don't want to create attribute route for each possible combinations. Since querystring can varies for diff options

e.g 
querystring  = "xyz" , "okd/asd", "abc/mln/usy/$/asds?app-version=1.1"

Comment: You want to use attribute routing.  See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 for details and examples.

Comment: This article specifialy target what you are looking for : http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-catch-all-route-parameter-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catch-all will help to solve this problem

[Route("api/values/{*query})]
IEnumerable GetAll(string query){

return query.split('\');

}